# How to plot from Counter library?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have this code

```
w = Counter(df['col'].sum())
```

and to plot is by using

```
plt.bar(w.keys(), w.values())
```

how to limit to plot by top ten most valued from w?
I tried to plot by using

```
w = Counter(twt['mentions'].sum()).most_common(10)
```

but it shown error: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`most_common()` returns a list of tuples (the most common `k` items of the Counter). To transform that in a `dict` so you can use it as per your line `plt.bar...`, do:

```py
w = dict(Counter(twt['mentions'].sum()).most_common(10))
```